# Html5 pushstate internal service error when page refresh, or view source code

Tags: ajax, html, pushstate, internal-server-error

i am attempting to copy a tutorial example found here http://html5.gingerhost.com/ but whenever i try to refresh the page it takes me to a "500 Internal Server Error". also when i click the link and the page loads the other content, when i look at the source code it only shows my another "500 Internal Server Error"

please help!

thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the server needs to be able to understand the URLs too. So for example, you're page is at `http://example.com`. You use a link's click event to make it `http://example.com/more-info`. But if `http://example.com/more-info` doesn't exist on the server, refreshing the page won't work properly because the browser won't know that `/more-info` is actually part of the index page. So pushstate only works if the client and the server both recognise the new URLs.

Comment: do you have any idea how to make the cliet recognize the new urls... htaccess??

Comment: yes, you could do it with an htaccess. Have a look here: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/